# merge two branches with excluding revisions which are merged from trunk

Tags: svn

I have copied two different branches (branch1, branch2) into my home directory.

**1-** I want to merge branch2 to branch1. Since both of them comes from one model, they have similar folders, and I want to keep the files from brach1. so I need to exclude the revisions which had been already merged to branch2.

I would appreciate that if you guide me how can I do it.

**2-** How can I see just the name of the files which is modified in brach2 respect to branch1?

svn diff gives me more detail of each files, just I need to know the name of the files without details.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check diff of code in branch by

```
    git diff branch1 branch2
```

If you need file which are changed then use --name-ony

```
    git diff branch1 branch2 --name only
```

To compare directory on different branch

```
    git diff branch1:folder_name branch2:folder_name --name-only
```